# how to work with wp_enqeue_scripts in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ok I have been dealing with this code for a week now... I don't want to give so please help me here :)

So i have this javascript file that I am trying to include into my plugin. When I try to use the wp_enqeue_script function, it does not work at all, but when I use the Include function it works perfectly, but only on my local server. If install the plugin on a hosted server it does not even install the plugin. where is the problem?

the file is located at /includes/links.js

How do i get wordpress to load this script, where do I include it? I have tried checking the wordpress codex but get me even more confused. If you need to check the code please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to getting a script to load:

```
<?php wp_register_script('script-handle', 'script-location'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('script-handle'); ?>
```

wp_enqueue_script will not load the script unless it has first been registered (note that WP comes with many pre-registered scripts, such as jQuery, so in that case all you need to do is enqueue the script.  But, for a custom script not bundled in WP, you'll need to register it first).

So, based on the question, AND assuming you've got the script located in the folder "includes" within your THEME directory (such as *wp-content/themes/my-theme/includes/links.js*), then this is what you would do in your theme's **functions.php** file:

```
<?php
    function my_theme_register_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('my-script-handle', get_bloginfo("template_url") . '/includes/links.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script-handle');
    }

    // If you want to use the script on the FRONT end of the site, then....
    add_action('init', 'my_theme_register_scripts');
    // If you want to use the script on the BACK end of the site....
    add_action('admin_init', 'my_theme_register_scripts');
?>
```

Also - David is right - you need to be sure your theme has both the wp_head() and wp_footer() calls in it, otherwise things will not work as expected...

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply cale_b... can I use that for a plugin?

Comment: Yes.  This will work in either theme or plugin files.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well first, check if the script is being loaded if not then check two things:

1) You enqueued it properly `wp_enqueue_script('script name',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/links.js','','',false);` assuming that your script is in the includes folder of your CURRENT theme

2) You have `wp_head()` somewhere in your header (assuming your loading in the head other wise you need `wp_footer()` but really you should have both.